# Installing Visual Studio 2012 via RDC

Tags: remote-desktop, visual-studio-2010

I am currently installing Visual Studio 2012 on a remote system that is connected to my LAN but I am having some trouble doing a visual install.  When I run vs_premium.exe to start the installation the actual install window appears but it is transparent. I know that it is there because I can drag the window around the screen (I get the standard Windows system outline of the window when I drag) and when I hover over the various links that appear on the window it changes my cursor.  I am currently running a silent install to get it installed but I was wondering if there is anything I can do to overcome this problem?

I have configured RDC to use the highest graphic settings and have configured the network settings by specifying that the remote system is part of my LAN but tweaking these settings doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? Je suis dans le same boat

Comment: Unfortunately I'm seeing the same thing with this.

Answer (score 2):

There's [a hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2661227) targetted at a similar sounding problem:

> Consider the following scenario:
>
> - You have a computer that has the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5
>     installed.
> - You use Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) to remotely access
>     the computer.
> - You try to run a .NET Framework 3.5-based Windows
>     Presentation Foundation (WPF) application on the remote computer.
>
> In
>   this scenario, the WPF application is not displayed correctly. For
>   example, the WPF application only has a border, and the body of the
>   application is not displayed.